# Why won't this variable increment?

Tags: javascript, html, operators

I am trying to make a simple clicker game, but ++ only increments the variable money by one. I could not find out why, because every time you click, it runs the function, increments the variable by one, and updates the text in the innerHTML. I looked so hard to find out why it wasn't working, and I could not find anything. Here is my JavaScript:

```
function ps() {
  var money = 0;
  money++;
  var d = document.getElementById("d");
  var a = document.getElementById("a");
  if (a.paused) {
    a.play();
  } else {
    a.currentTime = 0
  }
  d.innerHTML = "$" + money;
}
```

and here is my HTML:

```
<img onclick="ps()" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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">
<audio id="a">
  <source src="https://www.fesliyanstudios.com/play-mp3/6292">
</audio>
<div id="d">

</div>
```

Sorry for the huge image address. Can you figure out why it's not working?

Comment: It's a local variable, not a persistent variable; declare the variable outside for it to be persistent

Comment: to be clear, the ++ will only increment "money" by one and stop.